# Retrieving information from java service to Android app

Tags: java, android, json, spring

I am new to Android development and java services and I wanted to know how to implement this. I have a Java service using Spring (deployed on Tomcat, locally) and I can call a method in it called `getInfo()` that will send a JSON string of info. I want to know how to call this method `getInfo()` from my Android application and how to retrieve that JSON string? How do I communicate with the service? Please help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to do this on android. An OS library that I like to use for Rest calls in android is called Retrofit.

```
http://square.github.io/retrofit/
```

Retrofit works by turning your interaction into your web service into plain old java objects by abstracting away the http request and the parsing of the json response.